# Is it possible to keep a list of IPs/Websites which I don't want to use Tor to connect to?

Tags: torsocks

I am new to the Tor world, and I really like the idea of it!

But now I encountered some issue when I applied the "Torify" to my own python program

```
torify my_python_program
```

As stated in the URL:https://neverendingsecurity.wordpress.com/2015/03/14/proxify-applications-with-torsocks-tsocks-and-proxychains-on-linux/

This would make every requests made within my program go through Tor network.

This problem is that my python program would access various different websites, and **one of them is even in the LAN.**

By default, Tor will reject access to local addresses, and therefore I'll need to use its public IP/DNS. But What I really want is that **Tor would just redirect the requests to the normal un-torified network**.

Is this even possible with the current Tor implementation?

I am hoping there is some config I can change to keep a list of IPs that I want to access without Tor?